# Using Derivative with list in curly brackets

Tags: function-construction, list-manipulation, differentials

I'd like to make a formula for a sum containing `Derivative` where the number of arguments in the latter depends on an input parameter n. Also involved is a list `c` calculated before and a function `f` that has n inputs. Here's the version for n=2

```
c[[1,2]]*Derivative[c[[1,1,1],c[[1,1,2]]]][f][z1,z2]+
c[[2,2]]*Derivative[c[[2,1,1],c[[2,1,2]]]][f][z1,z2]+
c[[3,2]]*Derivative[c[[3,1,1],c[[3,1,2]]]][f][z1,z2];
```

And here for n=3:

```
c[[1,2]]*Derivative[c[[1,1,1],c[[1,1,2],c[[1,1,3]]]][f][z1,z2,z3]+
c[[2,2]]*Derivative[c[[2,1,1],c[[2,1,2],c[[2,1,3]]]][f][z1,z2,z3]+
c[[3,2]]*Derivative[c[[3,1,1],c[[3,1,2],c[[3,1,3]]]][f][z1,z2,z3]+
c[[4,2]]*Derivative[c[[4,1,1],c[[4,1,2],c[[4,1,3]]]][f][z1,z2,z3]+
c[[5,2]]*Derivative[c[[5,1,1],c[[1,1,2],c[[5,1,3]]]][f][z1,z2,z3]+
c[[6,2]]*Derivative[c[[6,1,1],c[[6,1,2],c[[6,1,3]]]][f][z1,z2,z3];
```

And so on. I was thinking about how I can make this more general and I think I can almost get it working using `sum`, doing something like (for n=4)

```
Sum[c[[i,2]]]*Derivative[Table[c[[i,1,j]],{j,1,4}]][f][z1,z2,z3,z4],{i,1,24}];
```

The problem with this is that `Table` outputs a list with curly brackets, and this won't work with `Derivative`, as seen from e.g. running

```
f[x_,y_]=x^2+5*x*y;
Derivative[1,1][f][x,y]
Derivative[{1,1}][f][x,y]
```

The first way works but not the second. Trying to get rid of the brackets I've tried `Flatten` with different inputs but that seems to only remove brackets inside brackets; I can't get rid of the outermost ones.

Does anyone know a way to get rid of the brackets from a `Table`, or use `Derivative` with a list in curly brackets? Or maybe a better way to do the whole thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want n! terms, this is the thing:

```
expr[n_] := Sum[c[[i, 2]] Derivative[Sequence @@ Table[c[[i, 1, j]],
{j, n}]][f][##], {i, n!}] & @@ ToExpression["z" <> ToString[#] & /@ Range[n]]
```

I'm not sure, but with 24 for n=4, I'm kinda convinced, even though you have 3 terms for n=2.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you very much! And yeah it is supposed to be n!, I have a typo in the n=2 example in the OP.